# GWT: How to migrate to gwt 2.8.2 from gwt 2.7.0

Tags: gwt

i have this problem with gwt 2.7.0: Datepicker is not anchored to the DateBox in Chrome.
I have tried an upgrade to gwt 2.8.2 but when i try to compile the code appears this exception:

```
[ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:111)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:76)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:76)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptImmutable(JModVisitor.java:305)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.visitChildren(JMethodCall.java:275)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:266)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement.traverse(JExpressionStatement.java:42)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:331)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:94)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:139)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JIfStatement.traverse(JIfStatement.java:53)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:331)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:94)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:139)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:135)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:786)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:778)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1401)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:896)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1410)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1222)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1140)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType.getMetaDataTags()[Ljava/lang/String;
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.ClassMenuGenerator.elabClass(ClassMenuGenerator.java:237)
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.ClassMenuGenerator.create(ClassMenuGenerator.java:204)
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.MenuGenerator.generate(MenuGenerator.java:14)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:103)
[INFO]  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:262)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:251)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  ... 56 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(343): GWT.create(CdnMenu.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(343): (SMenu) GWT.create(CdnMenu.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(343): (SMenu) (SMenu) GWT.create(CdnMenu.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(343): TemplateManager.setMenu((SMenu) (SMenu) 
GWT.create(CdnMenu.class))
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(343): TemplateManager.setMenu((SMenu) (SMenu) 
GWT.create(CdnMenu.class))
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement
[INFO]       [ERROR] at Cdn.java(165):
```

Here is one of the lines that goes into error:
TemplateManager.setMenu((SMenu) GWT.create(CdnMenu.class));

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Stefano

Answer (score 2):

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType.getMetaDataTags()[Ljava/lang/String;
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.ClassMenuGenerator.elabClass(ClassMenuGenerator.java:237)
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.ClassMenuGenerator.create(ClassMenuGenerator.java:204)
[INFO]  at org.googlecode.gwt.rebind.menu.MenuGenerator.generate(MenuGenerator.java:14)
```

It looks like your project has some MenuGenerator that it is using which is calling JClassType.getMetaDataTags, a method which seems to no longer exist. This method existed on an interface `HasMetadata`, which was [deleted in 2014](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/commit/35ddf664), but was [deprecated back in 2009](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/commit/4d72ede75), 12 years ago - as of that time it no longer functioned (according to the commit message).

---

Searching the web for the full classname of ClassMenuGenerator (and the package structure) shows that it was part of this project formerly hosted on Google Code, archived when that service shut down: [Productive GWT](https://code.google.com/archive/p/productive-gwt/). Those projects can be migrated to github, but I only found [one such migration had happened](https://github.com/search?q=productive-gwt&type=repositories), and even in that copy, [this issue has not been fixed](https://github.com/masini/productive-gwt/blob/master/gwt-framework/gwt-framework-client/src/main/java/org/googlecode/gwt/rebind/menu/ClassMenuGenerator.java#L237) - the fork is probably not maintained.

The good news is that fixing it should be easy, since as noted above, the metadata feature hasn't actually done anything since 2009, so you can probably just fork and remove the code that calls those metadata methods. Compiling the project against a recent version of GWT will also make it easier to figure out if there are any other issues lurking that might also cause problems.